# Can you have multiple and operators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
if ((showHideDropdown.target.id !== "gear-icon") && (showHideDropdown.target.id !== "gear-image") && (showHideDropdown.target.id !== "settings") && (showHideDropdown.target.id !== "profile-icon") && (showHideDropdown.target.id !== "profile-image")){
```

I always thought that multiple and operators can be used like this, but nothing after the first two target id's worked. Maybe this has nothing to do with the operators, which is why I am asking if you can have multiple operators in a line. I'm a beginner in js so I haven't met this kind of problem before.

Comment: Yes, multiple ANDs are fine. If you have an issue with this, please give details *what* doesn't work as well as a [mcve] so we can help you with it.

Comment: Just to let you know, you can write that condition as `if (!["gear-icon", "gear-image", "settings", "profile-icon", "profile-image"].includes(showHideDropdown.target.id))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple `&&` conditions, but you'd probably be better off simplifying your check since your conditions seem to have lots of repetition of the same field. For instance:

```
const id = showHideDropdown.target.id;
const list = [`gear-icon`, `gear-image`, `settings`, `profile-icon`, `profile-image`];

if (!list.includes(id)) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Using template literals, because...?

Comment: @RoboRobok because he likes to check his linter is working and removing them ;)

Comment: Oh, yeah, let's have a debate about if we all prefer single quotes or double quotes or template literals or tabs or spaces... very relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Using template literals like that has nothing to do with preference, it's just abusing JavaScript syntax.